# Temporarily modifying PATH variable from R session

Tags: r, path, environment-variables, plotly

## Background

I've generated a [plotly](https://plot.ly/r/) object that I would like to export using [`plotly::orca`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.9.0/topics/orca) function. The function has dependency on a command line utility orca that, I've installed and can find running `which` in terminal.

```
which -a orca
~/.conda/envs/dev_env/bin/orca
```

## Problem

`plotly::orca` calls support function `plotly:::orca_available` which makes use of `Sys.which("orca")`. In my case this returns an empty string.

## Solution attempt

I was thinking of temporarily modifying `PATH` variable and shoving in path to this orca thing:

```
withr::with_path(new = normalizePath(
    file.path(path.expand("~"), ".conda", "envs", "dev_env", "bin", "orca")
),
action = "prefix",
code {
# export graph, not relevant
 })
```

This fails with the same error. I've explored further and it seems like that adding path to that file manually has zero effect.

```
withr::with_path(new = normalizePath(file.path(
    "~", ".conda", "envs", "dev_env", "bin", "orca"
)),
action = "prefix",
code = {
    Sys.which("orca")

})

# orca 
#  ""
```

### *Question*

*How to correctly temporarily modify `PATH` variable in R session to add path to a specific package?*

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `file.path(path.expand("~"), ".conda", "envs", "dev_env", "bin")`? (Remove the trailing `"orca"` which, if I read right, is the executable itself and not the directory containing the executable.)

Comment: @r2evans You are right, that was my mistake.